# Why does Google Chrome generate 2 types of client hello message

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, handshake

I'm analyzing google chrome TLS client hello messages and I found that google chrome generate 2 types of fingerprints. One withe GREASE extensions and one without. I want to know why google chrome generate 2 types of client hello messages and based on what it send each time a type?
Please I need help

Comment: *"... I found that google chrome generate 2 types of fingerprints..."* - does it? When does it use which fingerprint. Is it for the same host? Do you have a pcap to analyze?

Comment: I meant by two types of fingerprints 2 types of client hello messages

Comment: Here is a pcap of google chrome clients hellos messages https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z_-kbUmD-Rtbv5Dqq6xV4IJvWubaxnmu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. Based on this pcap the difference seems to be to use either `TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV` or GREASE, while there can be different values for GREASE.

Comment: could you please explain to me this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In the past TLS implementations in servers and middleboxes often relied too much on behavior they've seen instead of behavior as standardized. This resulted in broken TLS handshakes when new ciphers or extensions were added. This was then worked around in clients by downgrading to older "known good" behavior by downgrading the TLS protocol version or not offering newer ciphers etc. Given that typical client successfully worked around broken systems there was no actual incentive to fix these systems.

Based on the market penetration and control Google has with its Chrome browser they've decided to tackle this problem in a more active way: on the one side they've nagged vendors to fix their implementations and on the other side they added some unpredictable "grease" to their clients so that system designers could not longer rely on a specific behavior but were forced to actually read and implement standards instead.

It looks like this grease is not done for all requests but only for a subset. And also different values for grease are used so that peer implementations cannot rely on a deterministic behavior. This matches what is described in [Applying Generate Random Extensions And Sustain Extensibility (GREASE)                          to TLS Extensibility - RFC 8701](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8701).

Comment: GREASE has been standardized in RFC8701 "Applying Generate Random Extensions And Sustain Extensibility (GREASE)
                          to TLS Extensibility" January 2020

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the answer with this information.

Comment: Regardless the presence of GREASE the clients hellos messages don't have the same order of cipher suites or list of extensions. Could you please explain to me what make the browser send a type of client hellos messages in each connections?

Comment: @AlaJebnoun: Are you really sure that this pcap is from Chrome only? Looking at the exact ciphers and order this looks for me like a mix of BoringSSL (used by Chrome) and OpenSSL (used by some other apps).

Comment: I used microsoft network monitor 3.4 to filter only the traffic generated by chrome

Comment: Otherwise, do you have an Idea how could I generate or filter the traffic generated only by chrome?

Comment: @AlaJebnoun: I'm not sure what you are doing. I just captured the traffic of my Chrome 80 and it only had a single type of handshake, differing only in the kind of grease but not in ciphers or cipher order. The cipher orders I see in your capture match the defaults from BoringSSL (used by Chrome) and OpenSSL so I expect that you have captured more than the traffic from Chrome.

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you do to capture only the traffic of Chrome 80, and thank you so much for your help

Comment: @AlaJebnoun: I just used a system were definitely only Chrome was running and captured its traffic using tcpdump.

Comment: There may be other process that are executed in the background and they are using TLS. Could you please provide me with your pcap?

Comment: @AlaJebnoun: *"Could you please provide me with your pcap?"* - No since this is private traffic. But just use all the ClientHello with grease in your own pcap - that's Chrome with BoringSSL.

Comment: Ok I have another question if you don't mind, does Google Chrome, Opera and Edge have the same Client Hello messages?

Comment: @AlaJebnoun: New questions should not be asked in a comment. But have a look at [SSLLabs](https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) for what different clients do.